# Updating built in Spring/Hibernate Archetype in Maven?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven-2, maven-archetype

The current version of Hibernate is 3.26 and Spring is 2.54 when I create a Spring and Hibernate project based off the default Archetype. How can I have Maven grab the newest release versions? I tried changing my spring version from 2.5.4 to 2.5.6 but 2.5.4 was still included in the generated war file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the dependency-plugin's [tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) goal you'll be able to see what artifacts are introducing a transitive dependency on the unwanted versions. To ensure they are not included in your war, you can then [exclude](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) those dependencies.

Say that some direct dependency `foo` introduces the spring 2.5.4 dependency, the following configuration would force Maven to not resolve that transitive dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>name.seller.rich</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Then declaring the 2.5.6 version in your POM means that your required version will be included:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` and see why the old version is still being pulled in.